# Spring-boot, tomcat-embedded -- how define catalina.properties?

Tags: tomcat, spring-boot, catalina, embedded-tomcat-8

When running spring-boot with tomcat-embedded,
how do I set/change these tomcat-config system-properties?

- https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/systemprops.html

I tried just adding -D... on the commandline, but doesnt seem to work.

Comment: you may have a look at [common application properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html) & [Embedded servlet containers](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-embedded-servlet-containers.html)

Comment: your 1st links provides, I guess, spring-equivalents for a few of the tomcat system-properties above, but there are many more in the tomcat-doc... your 2nd link -- hard to digest I think.... there is no simple way to just set the tomcat-doc properties when running embedded? or an example/link how to use configurators, etc, if required to achieve it, would be helpful.

Comment: The second link leads to 404...

Comment: The 2nd link should be: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-customizing-embedded-containers

Answer (score 1):

I am currently defining one of the catalina.properties via command line when starting my spring-boot application.

The property we are adding is: `tomcat.util.http.parser.HttpParser.requestTargetAllow`

The complete command I use to run the application is:

```
mvn -Dtomcat.util.http.parser.HttpParser.requestTargetAllow={} spring-boot:run
```

You should be able to append more catalina properties as follows:

```
mvn -Dtomcat.util.buf.StringCache.byte.enabled=true -Dtomcat.util.http.parser.HttpParser.requestTargetAllow={} spring-boot:run
```

And you could add any of the properties you mentioned here:
https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/systemprops.html

I ended up with this solution with the help of following posts:

https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60594

[Invalid character found in the request target in spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46251131/invalid-character-found-in-the-request-target-in-spring-boot)

Let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I put the -D properties in the .conf like such:

`JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dtomcat.util.http.parser.HttpParser.requestTargetAllow={}`

That's the way you do it for deployments, the maven style by Alvaro Lazaro is more for development purposes.