# how change catalina.properties file if it is read only in embedded tomcat using intellij idea

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, tomcat8.5

> I am trying to set a property in catalina.properties file but it is read-only file
>
> how to change this file using intellij idea

**I want to add following property**

```
tomcat.util.http.parser.HttpParser.requestTargetAllow=|{}
```

**I want to add this because I want to allow pipe and braces as request parameter**

> Please help me

Comment: Please answer me fast

Comment: Have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44379278/spring-boot-tomcat-embedded-how-define-catalina-properties

Comment: how to try this, the catalina.properties file is not allow to write

Comment: please help me if you can

Comment: Do not edit the file. Add -Dtomcat.util.http.parser.HttpParser.requestTargetAllow=|{} as a VM option. If you start your Application directly via your Main-class within Intellij, click Run -> Run... -> Edit Configurations...

Comment: thank you so much, this solve my problem. Jai Shree Ram @pma

Comment: @pma Thank you so much. Stumbled on this post and your response helped.